# Job contract renewal. When is it reasonable to expect one?

Tags: contract-extension

3 months before expiration I had a performance review with my supervisor who spoke very highly of my achievements. However, to be fair, imho he is the kind of person who would praise even the worst performer. To my question of possible renewal he replied with "judging from this review, clearly, I want you to stay. I would give it a 90% probability it will be renewed, but you know, in this world you never have the job until the official letter has arrived".

Now it's 2 months left. I know they are looking for someone to replace my colleague who had to resign (he left to get a graduate degree). Am I right to start panicking?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't panic but it's probably the right time to start asking if you should be looking for another role, it might get things moving or give you an indication.
Having said that I have seen peoples contracts literally get renewed a week before expiration. They were so busy with their work they almost forgot about it and rushed it through. Ask them and look around for another job just to be safe in case they don't renew.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be worried as there is still two months and these things will have a due process. I would however be prepared for the worst possible outcome and then you won't be stuck.

Update your CV and potentially start looking around for new jobs. If it gets to a couple of weeks before you are due to renew and still nothing, start applying for some other positions.

If at the end of your contract, they decide to renew it, that's great! You can now inform the places where you applied that you are no longer interested in pursuing the opportunity. If they do not renew it then you are in a perfect position to go to some interviews and get right into a new job.

There is no way of knowing what is happening from your company's point of view **unless you ask**. If you don't ask, you can only speculate. Companies all work differently and will give you differing notice for contract renewal.